# Shorthand for adding new values to a hash of arrays

Tags: perl

Below is a generalization of a block of code that I keep having to write when i want to build up a hash of arrays inside some sort of loop.

```
#get value and key that I want to use
my $value = getvalue();
my $key = getKey();

#add value to hash using key
if($hash_of_arrays{$key}){
    push(@{$hash_of_arrays{$key}}, $value);
}
else{
    $hash_of_arrays{$key} = [$value];
}
```

The if statement is very tedious to write for such a simple task but it needs to be done because pushing a value when its key is undefined in the hash causes problems. I'm just wondering if there is any shorthand to writing this - one where I dont have to write out `$hash_of_arrays{$key}` three times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`push @{ $HoA{$key} }, $value;` works perfectly well and is the recommended thing to do. If your code that uses it has "problems", then ask about those problems instead.

Comment: Well, now I'm not quite sure how I managed to cause an error the last time I tried that! I thought it caused a "not an ARRAY reference" error but that doesn't seem to happen for undefined variables. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't happen for undefs, but it does happen if you manage to put something like a string into `$HoA{$key}` before you try to treat it as an arrayref :)

Comment: This method is called autovivification.  Brian d Foy has an article on how to turn it off: http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1256

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, when you find yourself repeating code, make a function or an object that does this for you.

However, for this specific case, you might want to check out [Perl Recipe 13.15: Tie Example: Make a Hash That Always Appends](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch13_16.htm). You can just assign a value to the hash, and it will append it automagically to the underlying array.